# SQL Server Update column results in inconsistent result

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, replace, sql-update, temp-tables

I am doing a simple update on a SQL Server temporary table. When I update a single column with three separate statements, I get an inconsistent result, but when I update the same column inside a single SQL statement I get the expected expect. Please could someone point the difference between the two. Am I missing something?

Here is the SQL:

```
CREATE TABLE #EmailChanges 
(
    OldEmail varchar(100),
    NewEmail varchar(100)
)

INSERT INTO #EmailChanges(OldEmail)
VALUES
('no.body@ccc.abc.com'),
('foo.bar@abc.com'), 
('any.body@xyz.com')

UPDATE #EmailChanges SET NewEmail = replace(OldEmail, '@ccc.abc.com', '@new.domain.com')
UPDATE #EmailChanges SET NewEmail = replace(OldEmail, '@xyz.com', '@new.domain.com')
UPDATE #EmailChanges SET NewEmail = replace(OldEmail, '@abc.com', '@new.domain.com')

-- If I uncomment below sql and comment above three updates, I get desired output.
-- UPDATE #EmailChanges SET NewEmail = replace(replace(replace(OldEmail, '@ccc.abc.com', '@new.domain.com'), '@xyz.com', '@new.domain.com'), '@abc.com', '@new.domain.com')

SELECT * FROM #EmailChanges
```

This givens me following result:

```
OldEmail              NewEmail
--------------------- --------------------------
no.body@ccc.abc.com   no.body@ccc.abc.com
foo.bar@abc.com   foo.bar@new.domain.com
any.body@xyz.com      any.body@xyz.com
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your update sets the value for `NewEmail` in all rows based on the value in `OldEmail`. The third update overwrites the previous two updates.

So the first two are pointless. It is the same as just running

```
UPDATE #EmailChanges SET NewEmail = replace(OldEmail, '@abc.com', '@new.domain.com')
```

And that only alters one row.

For separate statements to work you could use

```
UPDATE #EmailChanges SET NewEmail = replace(OldEmail, '@ccc.abc.com', '@new.domain.com')
UPDATE #EmailChanges SET NewEmail = replace(NewEmail, '@xyz.com', '@new.domain.com')
UPDATE #EmailChanges SET NewEmail = replace(NewEmail, '@abc.com', '@new.domain.com')
```

Comment: Thanks Martin! Silly me! :(